# How to run "executable " on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian

- I can download Linux 32 bits version of Eclipse Installer to Ubuntu .
- I can "Run" it and sort of works.
- I can download Linux 32 bits version of Eclipse Installer to Rasbpian ( Raspberry Pi hardware).
- Instead of "Run" option I get "Open with..." and a dialog  enabling me to select  application to run "executable" files.

**I am lost - what application?**

I have been told that I cannot run x86 application on ARM architecture.

Is  that true?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14795541/932052

Comment: What is it you're downloading? Please provide a link.

Comment: Excuse me, did  you read the OP? I can download Linux 32 bits version of Eclipse Installer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You cannot run x86 software on the Raspberry Pi. You need to download software compiled for the Raspberry Pi, or download the source code and compile it yourself.

Comment: It's definitely possible to run undemanding x86 apps using emulators (I have played minesweeper and pinball from Windows XP using an emulator and Wine) but running something as heavy as Eclipse is not a good idea. Besides, Eclipse is already ported to ARM.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to install Eclipse on a Raspberry Pi, you should download it using the package manager:

```
apt-get install eclipse
```

Running x86 applications on ARM will require emulation, which means x86 Eclipse will run with an extremely poor performance, if at all.

Comment: apt-get install eclipse installs Eclipse 3.8 and Java only.It is a major task to try to update to ANY other version. Using Add/Delete Software menu is buggy and nobody seems to care. I am switching to Ubuntu to remotely programming RPi.

Answer (score 1):

Program C+++ control applications for RPi remotely from Eclipse running on Ubuntu. 
In view of all naysayers and technical (x86 /ARM)  and administrative ( no update from 3.8 ?) roadblocks  it is the only (reasonable) solution , to bypass RPi as development tool. I had high hopes for it.

Comment: +1, however, there are also other IDEs than Eclipse out there. For example, I see a lot of Linux users programming in [Code::blocks](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/codeblocks)

Comment: With due respect - I am asking about Eclipse. Your comment is rater superfluous and invitation to a discussion.There are always an options, aren't they?